# How to set a variable value to Field name in Firebase Cloud. Web/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to set the data I entered in a form to the Field name in Firebase.

It works perfectly fine in the 3rd line `$("#blogUID").val()` (Blogs/blogUID collection). However, when I try to set the Field name in the Stats/Blogs collection (10th line), I get the following error:

```
error.ts:166 Uncaught FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined
    at new ui (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-firestore.js:1:52471)
    at Vh (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-firestore.js:1:164122)
    at kh (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-firestore.js:1:163328)
    at _d.doc (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-firestore.js:1:280502)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/TeamSolheim_Page1.html:251:36)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:43090)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:41074)
```

```
1    $("#blog-submit-button").click(function(){
2        // Add a new document in collection
3        // db.collection("Blogs").doc($("#blogUID").val()).set({
4        //     blogDate:  $("#blogDate").val(),
5        //     blogLink:  $("#blogLink").val(),
6        //     blogTitle: $("#blogTitle").val(),
7        // })
8        // .then(function() { 
9            db.collection("Stats").doc($("Blogs").val()).set({
10                $("#blogUID").val():  $("#blogLikes").val(),
11           })
12           .then(function() { 
                console.log("Document successfully written!");
                $("#blog-form").hide();
                $("#create-form").show();
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Error writing document 2: ", error);
            });
    //     })
    //     .catch(function(error) {
    //         console.error("Error writing document 1: ", error);
    //     });
    })
```

Permissions are wide open to any authenticated user:

```
    match /Stats/Blogs {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
```

Things I've tried:

```
            var _temp  = $("#blogUID").val();
            console.log(_temp);
            db.collection("Stats").doc("Blogs").set($("#blogUID").val, 123)
            //db.collection("Stats").doc("Blogs").val().set({
                //_temp: $("#blogLikes").val(),

                //"$$_temp.val()":  $("#blogLikes").val(),
                //$$_temp:  $("#blogLikes").val(),
                //window['_temp']: $("#blogLikes").val(),
                //$("#blogUID").val: $("#blogLikes").val(),
                //_temp:  $("#blogLikes").val(),
                //'$("#blogUID").val()':  $("#blogLikes").val(),
                //doc.$("#blogUID"): $("#blogLikes").val(),
                //$("#blogUID").val():  $("#blogLikes").val(),
           // })
```

Here's the final code for prosperity...

```
    $("#blog-submit-button").click(function(){
        // Add a new document in collection
        db.collection("Blogs").doc($("#blogUID").val()).set({
            blogDate:  $("#blogDate").val(),
            blogLink:  $("#blogLink").val(),
            blogTitle: $("#blogTitle").val(),
        })
        .then(function() { 
            var _temp  = $("#blogUID").val();
            console.log(_temp);
            db.collection("Stats").doc("Blogs").set({
                [_temp]: $("#blogLikes").val()
           })
            .then(function() { 
                console.log("Document successfully written!");
                $("#blog-form").hide();
                $("#create-form").show();
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Error writing document 2: ", error);
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error writing document 1: ", error);
        });
    })
```

Comment: The error function is quite clear - the argument to .doc() is undefined - your line 9 shows .doc($("Blogs").val) - $("Blogs") doesn't look like a valid jsquery selector from here.  Your line 3 shows .doc($("#blogUID")), where $("#blogUID") looks like a valid jsquery selector for the element with ID "blogUID".

Comment: That helped, I changed line 9 to 'db.collection("Stats").doc("Blogs").set({' and I no longer get the error message. I still don't get the desired results on line 10. It is just writing "#blogID" to the database instead of the actual value I have stored in the variable.

Comment: I don't think you are specifying the set object correctly - I *think* you meant to write
{ [$("#blogUID").val()]:  $("#blogLikes").val()} to use the value of the of the jQuery-searched HTML element with ID #blogUID as the field name?  Set is expecting an ordinary object.

Comment: As a *style* issue, mixing in the jQuery HTML element reads into the Firestore commands is pretty unlikely to be efficient, and *very* likely to lead to errors, as they both have quite different interpretations of several similar characters.  Read your form elements into local variables, and use those in your Firestore calls to keep the responsibilities separate.

Comment: I've tried that, I just can't figure out the correct syntax. I've added the "Things I've Tried" section to the original post.

Comment: .set() needs an object - you had it "closer" on the first try.  Try this:

const blogger = $("#blogUID").val() // jQuery
const bloggerLikes = $("#blogLikes").val() // jQuery

db.collection("Stats").doc("Blogs").set( { [ blogger]:  bloggerLikes } )

you *need* the [] to use the blogger value as the index/fieldname

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moving down to an answer for formatting:

.set() needs an object - you had it "closer" on the first try.  Try this:

```
const blogger = $("#blogUID").val() // jQuery
const bloggerLikes = $("#blogLikes").val() // jQuery

db.collection("Stats").doc("Blogs").set( { [ blogger]:  bloggerLikes } )
```

you *need* the [  ] to use the blogger value as the index/fieldname

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as Community Wiki, based in the @LeadDreamer comment.

It seems by the stack trace that you error is related to the way that you are trying to query documents on line 9. From line 3, the `db.collection("Blogs").doc($("#blogUID").val()).set()` is correctly searching form the `blogUID`, where querying based in the `id` seems to be valid.

However, in your line 9, this `db.collection("Stats").doc($("Blogs").val()).set()` is not returning queries based in an `id`, as you can notice the difference between `#blogUID` and `Blogs` in the `.doc()` function. Since the error is informing that the issue is within the `.doc()` being undefined, please, change the way you are calling in line 9, to follow the same pattern from line 3.

Comment: First, in both cases, it is writing data (with the set command).

Comment: Secondly, it's a matter of where I'm trying to save the data. In line 3, I'm saving to \Blogs\BlogID\blogDate\blogDate. In line 10, I'm saving to \Stats\Blogs\BlogID\blogLikes. The data is stored using these terms Collection\Document\Field\Data. In line three, it saves fine to the Document name, however, in line 10, it fails to save to the Field name. It has data so why is calling it a 'non-empty' string??